# Missing symfony/acl-bundle documentation (Symfony4)

Tags: php, symfony

Is there "symfony/acl-bundle" documentation for Symfony4?

[GitHub page](https://github.com/symfony/acl-bundle) points to [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl_advanced.html) and Symfony back to GitHub. It looks official documentation is somehow missing.

Comment: Are you using Symfony 4.x?

Comment: Yes planning to use it in Symfony 4

Comment: Welp, you're right. It doesn't have documentation. I don't know what to tell you to be honest.

Comment: Actually been removed in S4 as the docs mention: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/acl.html

Comment: There is no more ACL in SF 4. You have to write it by yourself if you really need it. Otherwise consider using Voters if possible.

Answer (score 2):

ACL support was removed in Symfony 4 . But you can use [security voters](http://symfony.com/doc/master/security/voters.html) , the alternative recommended by Symfony